# Plotting two parametric regions together

Tags: plotting

I have the following code below, which allows me to plot two nice figures in the plane.

```
z = a + I*b;
f[z_] = 1 + z + z^2/2 + z^3/6 + z^4/24 ;
g[z_] = z + 1;
ParametricPlot[{a, b}, {a, -3, 1}, {b, -3, 3}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{a, b}, Abs[f[z]] < 1], MaxRecursion -> 4]
ParametricPlot[{a, b}, {a, -3, 1}, {b, -3, 3}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{a, b}, Abs[g[z]] < 1], MaxRecursion -> 6]
```

[image: images]

In order to put them together, I came up with the following.

```
z = a + I*b;
f[z_] = 1 + z + z^2/2 + z^3/6 + z^4/24 ;
g[z_] = z + 1;
ParametricPlot[{ConditionalExpression[{a, b}, Abs[f[z]] < 1], 
  ConditionalExpression[{a, b}, Abs[g[z]] < 1]}, {a, -3, 1}, {b, -3, 3}]
```

[image]

Now I got this terrible figure. Even setting `MaxRecursion` to it's maximum won't make difference. How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use `RegionFunction` again? `Function[{a, b}, Abs[f[z]] < 1 || Abs[g[z]] < 1]`? (Use `&&` if you want the intersection instead of the union.)

Comment: You mean inside or outside the conditional expression? Outside I'm not sure I want and inside I'm not sure how it works.

Comment: Hmmmm... I think I got what you mean, let me give a try.

Comment: I mean, ditch the conditional expression. Just use the union of the two regions as the setting for `RegionFunction`.

Comment: I was hoping to plot them in different colors too. Is there a chance to still do this?

Comment: Ah, if you want the two regions to be distinct, then just put them in separate `ParametricPlot[]`s and use `Show[]` to combine them.

Comment: Then, can you please write an answer to your own question?

Answer (score 5):

The code below solved my problem.

```
z = a + I*b;
f[z_] = 1 + z + z^2/2 + z^3/6 + z^4/24 ;
g[z_] = z + 1;
P1 := ParametricPlot[{a, b}, {a, -3, 1}, {b, -3, 3}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{a, b}, Abs[f[z]] < 1], 
   MaxRecursion -> 4];
P2 := ParametricPlot[{a, b}, {a, -3, 1}, {b, -3, 3}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{a, b}, Abs[g[z]] < 1], 
   MaxRecursion -> 4];
Show[P1, P2]
```

I got the following figure.

[image]

I was thinking about two different colors, but this two kinds of blue are just fine. Of course changing the colors are not a problem now, if I want to change. 
Thank you for the help, *Guess who it is*.

Answer (score 4):

I have upvoted the self answer. Just to illustrate another approach:

```
f[z_] := 1 + z + z^2/2 + z^3/6 + z^4/24;
g[z_] := z + 1
RegionPlot[{Abs[f[x + I y]] < 1, Abs[g[x + I y]] < 1}, {x, -3, 
  1}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]